# Using Nativescript RadDataForm: Property 'telerik' does not exist on type 'typeof com'

Tags: nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am trying to apply advanced styles to the UIStepper and SegmentedBar for the RadDataForm. I have been looking at [the examples](https://github.com/ProgressNS/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/tree/d0c759cbde291d70c2f52ccfd788c11677ad0a5f/dataform/app/examples/styling/advanced) and I can run the examples locally. When trying to implement it in my own app, I get a few errors though.

```
ERROR in src/app/round/new/new.component.style.ts:53:44 - error TS2339: Property 'telerik' does not exist on type 'typeof com'.

53         editor.setCustomizeButtons(new com.telerik.android.common.Procedure({
                                              ~~~~~~~
src/app/round/new/new.component.style.ts:75:37 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'TKGridLayoutAlignment'.

75         editorView.labelAlignment = TKGridLayoutAlignment.Left;
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

When looking around I found this [other Stack Overflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56222066/how-to-edit-nativescript-angular-raddataform-uistepper-on-ios/56224007) on using the `TKGridLayoutAlignment` and the simply declare it a variable to get rid of the error. I can use the same approach to get rid of that error but I still have the `Property 'telerik' does not exist on type 'typeof com'` to solve.

I have tried looking at the tsconfigs and package.json's in the examples but I cannot figure out what I need to do.

What configuration/packages do I need to be able to implement the advanced styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the reference.d.ts file was missing the dataform dependencies and only contained the android and ios references.

Currently the reference.d.ts should like like this for me:

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/nativescript-ui-core/ios.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/nativescript-ui-core/android.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/nativescript-ui-autocomplete/ios.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/nativescript-ui-autocomplete/android.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/nativescript-ui-dataform/ios.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/nativescript-ui-dataform/android.d.ts" />
```